# Where does the definition of the $L_0$ norm come from?

Tags: normed-spaces, vectors

Where does the definition of the $L_0$ norm come from?

$$\|x\|_0=|S|$$

Where $S=\{x_k:x_k\neq 0\}$

Comment: Where does it come from? Or what is it used for?

Comment: The $L_0$ norm of $x$ is $\sum\limits_k x_k^0$, in a similar manner to $L_p$ norms for $p \ge 1$, but avoiding the problem of dividing by zero that would come from exactly following the definition.

Comment: @qaphla It avoids the problems..but is is consistent with the definition?

Comment: It's not exactly following the definition of the $L_p$ norms, but it is defined in a similar way, and I'm under the impression that it being called $L_0$ is because of that similarity. I don't really know what you mean by 'consistent' here.

Comment: @qaphla In what way are they similar?

Comment: It does not satisfy $|\alpha x|=|\alpha||x|$ to say the least, so not really a norm.

Comment: $\Vert x \Vert_p = \left( \sum\limits_k x_k^p \right)^{1/p}$. $L_0$ is the same, but without the $0$th root taken at the end.

Comment: Understood, thanks. @qaphla

Answer (score 2):

The concept of this "norm" does *not* come from the desire to generalize $L^p$ norm. It comes from the desire to compress information. When you save a picture as JPEG file, information is stored in the form of a sequence of Fourier coefficients. To reduce the size of the file, we want to store as few coefficients as possible, and still have a decent image. Hence, one is led to consider minimization problems like 
$$
\|x\|_0 + \alpha \|x-x^*\|_2 \to\min \tag1
$$
where $x^*$ is the original image (or signal) and $x$ is the compressed one. The formula (1) attempts to balance the compression (small $\|x\|_0$) with accuracy (small $\|x-x^*\|_2$).

The terminology "$L_0$" comes from applied mathematicians who needed a name for the thing they were minimizing. Pure mathematicians would not name this thing (which isn't a norm) so.

Yes, there is formal similarity if we use the (unconventional) convention $0^0 = 0$: then 
$$\|x\|_0 = \sum x_k^0$$